# Magento Navigation Menu Bar With Thumbnail image

Tags: php, magento

i want to create drop down menu bar in magento with small image like advance menu bar please help i upload thumbnail image into category but that image is not show into menu bar now how can add image or show image into navigation menu

please help to show image into menubar

```
that like demo link 
http://blog.belvg.com/add-ons-on-friday-7.html
http://store.belvg.com/dropdown-menu.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this step you can display menu into navigation menu bar.

http://www.h-o.nl/blog/using_category_images_in_your_magento_navigation/

Answer (score 1):

Try following code to display Thumbnail image on the dropdown menu.

```
<?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_category->getThumbnail()  ?>" align="absmiddle" />
```